# How to remove Gimp logos from gimp interface?

Tags: gimp, interface

I've just downloaded gimp. Inside the interface I find two gimp logos - same as in gimp application icon - one in the interface and second one in the toolbox. Its kind of annoying and I want to remove it. So is there's any way to remove it?

Comment: That's. Wilbur (the Wolf), not 'a doggy image'. I don't.think you can, justignoreit. You may be to remove it with an installable theme.

Comment: @wilf You mean that is a wolf? I always thought it was like a mouse or something..

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the gimp logo from the toolbox by adding this line to the `gimprc` file in `~/.gimp2.8`

```
(toolbox-wilber no)
```

You should be able to add it using this command

```
echo "(toolbox-wilber no)" >> ~/.gimp-2.8/gimprc
```

or this *(which seems to work...)*, if you are using a version other than 2.8:

```
echo "(toolbox-wilber no)" >> ~/.gimp*/gimprc
```

You can remove this by running:

```
sed -i "/toolbox-wilb/d" ~/.gimp-2.8/gimprc
```

There seems to be no way to remove the main central logo.

for other options you can search the rc files located at `/etc/gimp/2.0` with

```
grep -rni "SEARCHTERM" -C 3 /etc/gimp/2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

in Gimp 2.10 you can go to Edit > Preferences > Interface > Toolbox > Uncheck Show Gimp logo